# Images rendering as characters in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I recently launched a simple single page portfolio site via Google App Engine (NodeJS) and everything works fine except when you click on an image gallery.  The images render slowly and come across as:

> ����tExifII*>F(i�N���0230���

That is just the 1st paragraph. It goes on and on. I reached out to Google and while extremely helpful they determined it was something with my javascript. Bummer. They recommended I post here and see if anyone else could see where I have gone wrong. I have reviewed the other App Engine image questions and I can't find one similar to mine. It's either python or something I have already tried.

My directory layout is:

- node_modules
- public
  -css
  -img
  -js
  -less
  -vendor
- app.js
- app.yaml
- package.json

  Here is my app.js:

  ```js
     
     'use strict';
     
     req

  uire('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start();

  var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');

  var app = express();
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.all('/', function(req, res) {       
      res.sendFile('index.html', { root: 'public'});
  });

  app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("I'm listening...");
  })
  ```

Here is my app.yaml (side note...1st time coming across a yaml file so this could be it):

```js
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /img
  static_dir: img
```

And here is the index.html for you minus everything but the header, the end of body scripts and the html where I have the gallery via a Bootstrap carousel:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:200|Cormorant" rel="stylesheet">
    

    <!-- Plugin CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h2>Some of My Work</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item gallery" style="padding-bottom: 30px">                         
                                <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/1.jpg" class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">                 
                                  <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/entertainment/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                      <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                        <div class="project-category text-faded">Category</div>
                                            <div class="project-name">Entertainment</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                         <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/1.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/2.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/3.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/4.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/5.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/6.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/7.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/8.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/9.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                  <!-- Controls -->
                                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                  </a>
                                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>                   

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item gallery" style="padding-bottom: 30px">                         
                                <a href="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/2.jpg" class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-lifestyle-modal-lg">                 
                                  <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/lifestyle/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                      <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                        <div class="project-category text-faded">Category</div>
                                            <div class="project-name">Lifestyle</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal fade bs-lifestyle-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div id="carousel-example-lifestyle" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                         <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/1.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/2.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/3.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/4.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/5.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/6.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/7.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/8.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/9.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/portfolio/fullsize/lifestyle/10.jpg" alt="...">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>

                                  <!-- Controls -->
                                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-lifestyle" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                  </a>
                                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-lifestyle" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>                            
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->                    
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/creative.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And lastly here is my creative.js:

```js
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Initialize and Configure Scroll Reveal Animation
    window.sr = ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('.sr-icons', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 200);
    sr.reveal('.sr-button', {
        duration: 1000,
        delay: 200
    });
    sr.reveal('.sr-contact', {
        duration: 600,
        scale: 0.3,
        distance: '0px'
    }, 300);

    

})(jQuery);
```

The last last thing... there are no errors in the console to refer too. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Note that the App Engine Flexible Environment doesn't support the static_dir option for serving static files; see 
[Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files) for details.  You're doing the right thing using express.static to serve the /public folder.

It looks like the server is serving an incorrect Content-Type for your images.  Check the HTTP headers (using the Network tab in your browser's debugger) to see if this is the case.

I just did some testing locally with node.js and Express, and it looks like it uses *serve-static*, which uses *send*, which uses *mime*, which guesses the Content-Type based on the file extension.  Does the image that's coming out wrong have a filename without an extension, or with an incorrect extension?

Comment: Thanks for the response Phillip. Checking the http headers I see this: HTTP/1.1 200 OK. Powered by Express. Content-Type: image/jpeg. Connection: Keep alive. And in the request Header there is this: GET /img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/1.jpg HTTP/1.1.

Comment: All of my img files have .jpg extensions. And all are numbered photos 1 through 10. The image I just tried to open has references to Adobe photoshop and HP copyright in the various characters that should be the image. I read the 'Serving Static Files' the external link to Express and I feel like I have both set-up properly. Am I missing something there?

Comment: Hmm... it looks like it's sending with the correct Content-Type.  I wonder if maybe Express could have corrupted the image.  If you download one of the images and reopen it, does it work?

Can you post a link to the site so I can take a look?

Comment: Here is the site: [link](http://nedabridgemanphotography.com). It's not allowing me to download the image. I checked out the 'view page source' and there are all of the links to the images which when clicked render just fine in chrome.

Comment: Ah.  This isn't an App Engine issue... what's happening here is that something in your Javascript is loading the image data and dumping it into your modal-content div as HTML.  This hangs Chrome for ~20 seconds for me, but once it comes back to life, I could open the div in the inspector and see the data in there.  I don't see where in the Javascript this is happening, but suspect that somewhere you're telling Bootstrap to use the JPEG as the content for a modal dialog, when you need to be putting an <img> tag in there instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PhillipPearson. I saw the edits and approved. At least it's been narrowed down. A quick look and I don't see any obvious missing <img> tags. I think the problem may be with the <a href> in my portfolio item gallery. Again, thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, seeing a few other examples the one that worked was this one from [alt-web: Bootstrap Modal + Carousel Tutorial](http://alt-web.com/TUTORIALS/?id=bootstrap_modal_carousel_gallery)

Here is an example of my working modal/carousel:

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h2>Some of My Work</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="portfolio-item" style="padding-bottom: 30px">                         
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                              <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#entertainmentModal"><a href="#entertainmentGallery" data-slide-to="0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/entertainment/1.jpg"><br>
                                Entertainment</a></li> 

                              <!--begin modal window-->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="entertainmentModal">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                               <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                 <div class="pull-left">My Entertainment Gallery</div>
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                                 </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                <!--CAROUSEL CODE GOES HERE-->
                                 <!--begin carousel-->
                                  <div id="entertainmentGallery" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
                                   <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item active"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/1.jpg" alt="item0"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/2.jpg" alt="item1"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/3.jpg" alt="item2"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/4.jpg" alt="item3"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/5.jpg" alt="item3"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/6.jpg" alt="item3"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/7.jpg" alt="item3"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/8.jpg" alt="item3"></div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="img/portfolio/fullsize/entertainment/9.jpg" alt="item3"></div>                                    
                                  </div><!--end carousel-inner-->
                                  <!--Begin Previous and Next buttons-->
                                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#entertainmentGallery" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#entertainmentGallery" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                                  </div><!--end carousel-->
                                </div><!--end modal-body-->
                                
                               </div><!--end modal-content-->
                              </div><!--end modal-dialog-->
                            </div><!--end myModal-->

                        </div><!-- /.container -->


                        </div>
```